# android studio running code on phone auto turns off.I think there is something wrong in my layout design but i cant figure out why

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio running code on phone auto turns off.
I am trying to build a translator application.
I think there is something wrong in my layout design but I cant figure out what.

I divided my homepage into two parts.

This is my activity_home layout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bwall1"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="nf.co.hoptec.ocr.Home">




    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/cameraicon"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/fab2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fab2" tools:targetApi="lollipop"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"

        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/imageicon"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="72dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="47dp" tools:targetApi="lollipop"/>

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_home"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my content_home layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="nf.co.hoptec.ocr.Home"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">


    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/source"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#F7F9FC"
                android:text="::  Source Language  ::"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/proceedbutt"
                android:layout_width="20dip"
                android:layout_height="20dip"
                android:background="#00ffffff"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/proceed"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/speakerbutt"
                android:layout_width="20dip"
                android:layout_height="20dip"
                android:background="#00ffffff"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/speaker"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/proceedbutt"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/copy"
                android:layout_width="20dip"
                android:layout_height="20dip"
                android:background="#00ffffff"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/copy"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/speakerbutt" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ocrtext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30.0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30.0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Type here to translate"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/ocrimg" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/target"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#F7F9FC"
                android:text="::  Result Language  ::"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/nth"
                android:layout_width="20dip"
                android:layout_height="20dip"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:background="#00ffffff"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/xparent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/speakerbutt1"
                android:layout_width="20dip"
                android:layout_height="20dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/nth"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="#00ffffff"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/speaker" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/copyt"
                android:layout_width="20dip"
                android:layout_height="20dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/speakerbutt1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="#00ffffff"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/copy" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ocrtextt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30.0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30.0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="?attr/editTextBackground"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="10sp" />

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Can you tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of constraint layout.Constraint layout is new layout of Android in which you can just drag and drop buttons,textview and all but it may looks perfect in preview but not in your phone because every device have different size of display screen so constraint layout will work different in different android phones and you may also be getting warning or error in that layout file.So try to use LinearLayout or RelativeLayout and then errors will not come.